# how to get all the subscribed category to b true

Tags: php

i have two tables

**subscribed**

[image]

**categorys**

[image]

```
public function get_categories($user_id)
{
    $categories = $this->ApiModel->categories();
    $subscribed = $this->ApiModel->get_categories($user_id);
    $subscribed = explode(',', $subscribed->categorys);
    foreach($categories as $category)
    {
        foreach($subscribed as $sub)
        {
            if($category->category == $sub)
            {
                $status = 'true';   
            }
            else
            {
                $status = 'false'; 
            }
        }
        $data = array('id' => $user_id, 'name' => $category->category, 'is_subscribed' => $status);
        echo json_encode($data);
    }
}
```

the result i m getting is

```
{"id":"3","name":"News","is_subscribed":"false"}{"id":"3","name":"Movies","is_subscribed":"true"}{"id":"3","name":"Sports","is_subscribed":"false"}{"id":"3","name":"Music","is_subscribed":"false"}
```

how to get all the subscribed category to b true

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is add a `break;` when you find a match in the inner loop. It will also speed up the processing.

```
public function get_categories($user_id)
{
    $categories = $this->ApiModel->categories();
    $subscribed = $this->ApiModel->get_categories($user_id);
    $subscribed = explode(',', $subscribed->categorys);

    $data = array();

    foreach($categories as $category){
        foreach($subscribed as $sub){
            if($category->category == $sub){
                $status = 'true'; 
                break;                //<-- new line
            } else {
                $status = 'false'; 
            }
        }
        //$data = array('id' => $user_id, 'name' => $category->category, 'is_subscribed' => $status);

        $data[] = array('id' => $user_id, 'name' => $category->category, 'is_subscribed' => $status);

        //echo json_encode($data);
    }
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

Comment: here i m getting response like this{"id":"3","name":"News","is_subscribed":"false"}{"id":"3","name":"Movies","is_subscribed":"true"} but i want the response like this [{"id":"3","name":"News","is_subscribed":"false"},{"id":"3","name":"Movies","is_subscribed":"true"}]